# Link to a specific page inside facebook TAB

Tags: facebook

Hallo guys can you pls explain me a way to create an url that link to a certain page inside a facebook tab?

I've this tab with index.php page1.php page2.php

i want to create a link that i can share with my users that lead them directly to page2.php.

I saw that i've to pass a string on app_data but then how can i get it back? cause my idea was this: http://facebook.com/app_id&app_data=gotosomewhere

```
if(gotosomewhere)
  header location
```

but i can't figure out how to get app_data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you are looking for will be placed inside the `signed_request` that is passed to your application the first time it is loaded.

[There is a page in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) that talks about what fields you can expect to see when inspecting your signed_request.

> **app_data** - A JSON string containing the content of the app_data query string parameter which may be passed if the app is being loaded within a Page Tab.

Comment: the think i don't unserdtand about this sdk (first time i working on it) is: if i include the sdk inside my page and i set up the app id etc etc then ill get all those datas automatically?

Comment: You will have to use the SDK in order to decode the `signed_request` - so yes. The signed request is passed automatically to your application even without the SDK, but you must have the SDK in order to decode it.

Comment: actually, you can decode it without the sdk, but the sdk makes it a lot easier. no extra function needed, just "getSignedRequest".

Comment: why this won't work require_once "includes/_lib/facebook.php";     $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
var_dump($signed_request);

Comment: @StefanoCerelli - that's really not enough information... Is the signed request even there? Are there any errors? What exactly does "won't work" mean?

Comment: code:
include("includes/lib/facebook.php");

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
var_dump($signed_request);  
?>

Error:
Notice: Undefined variable: facebook in /var2/site/homepage.php on line 6

Fatal error: Call to a member function getSignedRequest() on a non-object in /var2/site/homepage.php on line 6

Comment: @StefanoCerelli You are not including the SDK correctly...  `Undefined variable: facebook `.. Please ensure that you are initializing the SDK [as the documentation explains](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)...

Comment: OK i've created $facebook= new($key,$secretkey);
now the error is: NULL 
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /var2/site/includes/head.php on line 2

Comment: @StefanoCerelli - that is not an error... it is a notice... Your questions now are related to Facebook. Please make sure there are no other errors in your code and only after that start working with the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs, this is the way solved this problem.

facebook_data.php:

```
    <?php
    define('APP_ID',      'hereyourappid');
    define('APP_API_KEY', 'hereyourappid');
    define('APP_SECRET',  'hereyoursecretappid');
    error_reporting(0) ; 


    $signed_request = parse_signed_request(@$_REQUEST['signed_request'], APP_SECRET);
    defin

e('LIKED', @$signed_request['page']['liked']);

$app_data = $signed_request['page']['liked'];
$redirect = $signed_request['app_data']; /* HERE I DECLARE A VARIABLE 
THAT GET THE PARAMETER I PASS VIA URL */
$fanGate=LIKED;

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = @explode('.', $signed_request); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

?>
```

Now inside my fangate (index.php) i do:

```
<?php 
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
header("Set-Cookie: SIDNAME=ronty; path=/; secure");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
@session_start();
include('includes/facebook_data.php.php');


$sezione='fangate';
$pagina = '';
?>

<?php if(!LIKED): ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include("includes/head.php"); ?>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php include("includes/fb.php"); ?>
    <div id="fangate">
            <!-- your fangate -->
            <?php include("includes/footer.php");?>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
elseif($redirect == "gotopage"):
    header('Location: page2.php');
else:
    header('Location: homepage.php');
endif;
?>
```